# Graphometric Signature Android library

Tags: signature

Are there any libraries about Graphometric Signature for Android platform? I found only Olivetti toolkit, but I would use a free library for my Android App.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got the same task last year. The one which looked best is http://www.signotec.com/internet/page.php?naviID=900000026&site=900000025&typ=2&s_sprache=en but it's not free at all.

Some others:

- http://www.xyzmo.com/en/products/Pages/digital-signature-ipad-android.aspx
- http://www.androidpit.de/de/android/market/apps/app/com.xyzmo.signature/SIGNificant-E-Unterschrift
- http://www.binarysolutions.biz/2010/12/signature-capture-for-android.html
- http://www.supersignature.com/default.aspx
- http://www.gocanvas.com/content/blog/post/create-your-own-android-mobile-app-with-signature-capture-in-5-minutes
- https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=AB.AN&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDEsIkFCLkFOIl0
- https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rockalldesign.signaturesaver&feature=also_installed

Comment: Thank you @Marvin, the signotec protuct is a App not a library or SDK..I'm looking for a library..

Answer (score 2):

you can try Namirial S.p.A. solution.

http://www.graphosign.com/

http://www.firmagrafometrica.it/

You can use the Namirial solution with Windows, Android & iOs.

They also provide an sdk for the all platform.

For more information you can send an email to: info@graphosign.com

Comment: and also the Namirial eSignAnyWhere platform with its HTML5 based clients allows recording biometric signatures. Namirial provides Android/iOS/Windows Apps and also SDKs that embed this HTML5 based components and add the layer to record biometric signatures.

Visit https://saas.esignanywhere.net to get a free trial, and search for the SignAnywhere App on PlayStore.